# How to redirect HTML Emails to Client Browsers with Play 2.0

Tags: playframework-2.0

From my Play application I send welcome email when the registration process completes... and I'd like to provide the ability to view its content in the client's web browser. I've tried something like this...

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)

...

<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>

        ...

    </head>

    ...

    <p>Trouble viewing this email? <a href="@views.html.emails.email(title)(content)">View in Browser</p>

    ...

    <body>
        @content
    </body>
</html>
```

... but this code always ends up with a [StackOverflowError: null]:

```
In /home/j3d/Projects/test/app/views/mails/email.scala.html at line 8.

 5 <html>
 6 <head>
 7    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 8    <title>@title</title>
 9    <style type="text/css">
10        a { color: #4A72AF; }
11        body, #header h1, #header h2, p { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
12        #main { border: 1px solid #cfcece; }
```

Any help would be really appreciated :-)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are including your email template in the `a href=""`, instead of putting the link to this page.

You display the `views.html.emails.email` view, which include the `views.html.emails.email` view, which include the `views.html.emails.email` view... You've understand ;)

The solution is to put a real link (and not a content) in your `a` tag. Something like that (I don't know your controllers/routes):

```
<a href="@routes.Emails.showEmailAction(....)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your `@title` is null, make sure in the controller that it's String has value or set some default value for it in the view:

```
@(title: String="Email was sent, check your mailbox")(content: Html)
```